# configuring facebook sdk to eclipse

Tags: android, facebook

I am totally getting confused in creating project in eclipse.

1. For create project from existing source which path I should assign
2. Should I need to unzip Facebook.zip file
3. Please someone assist for configuring the project, I struck-ed in the scratch itself......

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this to use Facebook in Your application. Follow the steps mentioned [Facebook](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

This is the official guide in the subject.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/

Warning: When you come to step were you start using Keytool and they got a commandline for you to copy & paste. This will not work since they have put Enters in it.

Edit it yourself or copy this instead:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```